Finding element on website and insert value does not work
I am currently trying to set up a script which copies a value from Excel and inserts it into a specific field on a website. However, I am currently not able to so on a corporate website, on another script on www.google.com it worked.
Below, you see the code which I used to insert the value 'x' into Google search bar which also worked
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


search_value = 'x'  

chromedriver_path = r"C:\Users\QXZ5FRL\PycharmProjects\TestTest\venv\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
time.sleep(2)

try:
    cookie_accept_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="L2AGLb"]/div')
    cookie_accept_button.click()
except Exception as e:
    print("Cookie-Zustimmungsbutton nicht gefunden:", e)


search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')  
search_box.clear()  
search_box.send_keys(search_value)  
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  

time.sleep(5)  

driver.quit()

Now you see the code for my project, where the code does unfortunately not work.
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver_path = r"C:\Users\QXZ5FRL\PycharmProjects\TestTest\venv\Scripts\chromedriver.exe"

service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

try:
    driver.get("https://.net/hlrn/login.do") #corporate website thus not complete
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)

    button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "idToken4_1") # Field to click for login
    button.click()

    driver.get("https://.net/hlrn/rechercherechnung.do") #corporate website thus not complete
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)

    excel_file = r'C:\Users\QXZ5FRL\Desktop\SOKU Nummer mit Mail.xlsx'  
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

    df['ID_Client'] = df['ID_Client'].dropna()
    eindeutige_werte = df['ID_Client'].unique()

    for wert in eindeutige_werte:
        if pd.isna(wert):
            continue

        wert = str(int(wert))  
        print(f"Einzufügender Wert: {wert}")  

        try:
            input_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "kundenNummer")
            input_field.clear()
            input_field.send_keys(wert)
            input_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

            time.sleep(1)  

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Einfügen des Werts '{wert}': {e}")

finally:
    # Schließe den Browser
    driver.quit()

Following this statement: "try: input_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "kundenNummer")"
code is not executed anymore
Einzufügender Wert: 53611
Fehler beim Einfügen des Werts '53611': Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="kundenNummer"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=129.0.6668.101); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6A116B095+29557]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A10DFA50]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A0F9B56A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A0FEF695]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A0FEF8EC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A103B777]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A10171CF]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A103851C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A1016F33]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A0FE116F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A0FE22D1]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6A149C96D+3378253]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6A14E8497+3688311]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6A14DD1CB+3642539]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6A122A6B6+813462]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A10EAB5F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A10E6B74]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A10E6D10]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6A10D5C1F]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFA13367374+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFA14CFCC91+33]

Here you also find the element of the field I try to paste the excel value in:
<input type="text" name="kundenNummer" maxlength="15" size="16" value="">

enter image description here

I'm guessing that element is nested inside a <frame> element.

Yes, it is located in a frame: 

Thanks to your hint with frame, i solved it by this:
try:
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "rechercherechnung"))
)
        input_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "kundenNummer"))


It looks like selenium is unable to find element.
There can be multiple reasons, selector issues, element is not properly loaded, or element is under iframe.
if element loading issue you can try webdriverwait as following
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
input_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "kundenNummer")))

target webpage needs login otherwise I will quickly test and provide working solution.
